# UrlFetchApp.fetch returns bad request but service call works in the browser

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a google add-on that uses a restservice (GET). When I call the service from the address bar of the browser it works.
When I execute the code below I get "Bad request" as response.

```
function execute() {
  var service= restservice;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(service);
  Logger.log(response);
  return;
}
```

The scope script.external_request has been added to the manifest.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `restservice`? Maybe your service doesn't allow requests made from google-apps-scripts. Maybe your service is expecting a few headers (or not expecting them). If you replace your `restservice` with a request to `http://www.google.com/`, do you get the same response? If so, the problem is within your app. If not, the problem is on the `restservice`.

Comment: You haven't posted enough to create an MCVE.

Comment: The restservice is already used by an other project and is works fine for that project. I already tested with `http://www.google.com/` , and this returns the correct response. I also tried with the companies website that has the same domain as the restservice and this also worked fine.

Comment: Based on your comment, I imagine the problem is with headers/cookies. Try to replicate the manifest from the other projects into this project. The best thing, though, would be sharing the code here, so we can analyse it and give a proper answer without imagining things.

Comment: The other project that uses this restservice is not a google add-on, so I can not use that manifest. This is the code I execute. I will not add the correct url , but i can tell you that the url has 2 parameters (an email and a text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the problem.

The rest service was translated to an internal IP address.

Comment: Yeah if Google can't reach the IP that'd definitely be a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

From Gmail Add-ons documentation:

> If the add-on script uses UrlFetch to retrieve data, you must
>   whitelist the URLs it accesses using the urlFetchWhitelist field in
>   the add-on manifest.

Perhaps this will work with non-Gmail add-ons as well?
More details https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish

Comment: I already whitelisted  the URLs and this doesn't change a thing. The URL works when I use OpenLink.

Comment: With the amount of information you provided, it’s not possible to test further unless you post more information about the REST service